# Get nameservers I specify to stick

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I use a VPN for work. In network manager, for both my normal wired connection, and for the VPN connection also, I have it configured to "Automatic (VPN) addresses only" and I specify the nameservers I want to use. But when I view /etc/resolv.conf after connecting to the VPN, it shows different nameservers. Even after disconnecting from the VPN, it's using those nameservers that I did not specify.

The problem is this causes a large delay in browsing the web because the VPN nameservers are either really slow or maybe it's timing out.

How can I get it to stick to using the nameservers I specify?

If I edit resolv.conf and set it to the nameservers I want, the delay goes away, so I know this is the problem. But every time I use connect to the VPN, it just overwrites it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMPORTANT NOTE:

Starting from Ubuntu 12.04, some changes has been introduced into DNS resolving. It was announced [**here**](http://www.stgraber.org/2012/02/24/dns-in-ubuntu-12-04/) (*Do read the **VPN** part*). Also see its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/resolvconf.8.html). Changes state that

> resolvconf is a set of script and hooks managing DNS resolution. The
>   most notable difference for the user is that any change manually done
>   to /etc/resolv.conf will be **lost** as it gets overwritten next time
>   something triggers resolvconf. Instead, resolvconf uses DHCP client
>   hooks, a Network Manager plugin and /etc/network/interfaces to
>   generate a list of nameservers and domain to put in /etc/resolv.conf.

You can refer to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/130459/63025) on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: I'm reading through all that and trying various things but it still is automatically injecting 2 nameservers in resolv.conf whenever I connect to the VPN. I gave up and just made /etc/resolv.conf a regular file.

Comment: If you want to add more entries to `/etc/resolv.conf`, create a `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` and add them there, BUT If `/etc/resolv.conf` contains `127.0.0.1`, then adding entries to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` won't really do anything useful. You should instead set the list of DNS servers **statically** in **Network Manager** which will then be configured in `dnsmasq` (that's running on 127.0.0.1).

Comment: 127.0.0.1 does show up. As I explained in my question, I did specify static DNS servers in Network Manager. But it appears to be ignoring them.

Comment: I would really suggest asking this question in Ask Ubuntu .I believe you will get better answer there , since Ubuntu related. Please unaccept this answer , since it doesn't solves your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer led me to a solution, so I'll leave it accepted. Your reference to the question on Ask Ubuntu has very useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Set `resolv.conf` to be immutable with `chattr`.